# How do I install and use Python 3.8 on an Amazon EC2 Linux Instance?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I followed a tutorial to install python 3.8 and I'm able to use it by doing the command `python3.8`, but for some reason the code in my main.py file is still running on python 3.7. If I enter `python3.8 main.py`, I get errors saying that I don't have modules installed. I don't know how to install my modules on python 3.8 because when I do `sudo python3.8 -m pip install pymongo` it says `sudo: python3.8: command not found`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that `python3.8` works, but `sudo python3.8` gives a command not found error?

Comment: what is the output of your `type python` and `type python3` and `type python3.8` ?

Comment: "followed a tutorial" - which tutorial? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @causaSui Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Marcin https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-8-ubuntu/

Comment: @azbarcea `type python` outputs `python is /usr/bin/python`. 
`type python3` outputs `python3 is /usr/bin/python3`. 
`type python3.8` outputs `python3.8 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python3.8)`. 

I'm not really sure what this means.

Answer (score 45):

Amazon has it's own Linux with extras, the command is:

```
    sudo amazon-linux-extras install python3.8
```

taken from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-linux.html but after installing 3.7 from there, there is the above update command appearing during the install telling how to upgrade.  Ahh the convolution of hosted virtual machines, still easier than trying to get a console command line login on any other Linux on AWS.

It does rebuild the python to 3.8, cleaning up files from 3.7, so boom a clean build of 3.8 thanks to Amazon.

All that being said, the default "python" will still be 2.7 as there is no backward compatibility, and many think getting rid of 2.7 will cause problems.

So what **NOT TO DO NEXT as we are done** is:

```
    sudo rm /usr/bin/python  (which is only a link to /usr/bin/python2.7)
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

but usually peeps simply type python3.8 to specifically run the new version.

Comment: Thanks!, the `sudo amazon-linux-extras install python3.8` helped me installing it in my cloud9 instance :)

Comment: Is there a way to install an older version of Python using amazon-linux-extras? say python 2.7?

Answer (score 6):

These answers are now out of date as of Amazon Linux 2023.
[Amazon Linux 2023 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023/faqs/)

**Q: Does AL2023 have Amazon-Linux-Extras like AL2?**

A: No, AL2023 does not have extras. For higher-level software packages like language runtimes, we will use the quarterly release where we will add major/minor updates to packages as separate namespaced packages in addition to the default package provided in the repository. For example, default Python version in Amazon Linux 2023 may be 3.8, but we will add Python 3.9 (python39) as a separate namespaced package whenever it is made available. These additional packages will closely follow their upstream release cadence and support model and their support policies can be accessed by the package manager for compliance and security use cases. Default packages will continue to be supported throughout the life of AL2023.

Python is installed by default as `python3` exact version is managed by Amazon.  It is possible to pick a different version, but I have not found the instructions, since the currently install 3.9 works for my needs.

python3 --version
Python 3.9.16

python3x --version
always generated
`-bash: python3x: command not found`
regardless of choice of x

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use a package available via yum instead of getting from Amazon Extras. This way works for Amazon Linux 2:

```
yum install -y python38 python38-devel
```

Comment: No, getting error message as "No package python38 available"

Comment: @encryptedname are you sure you're running Amazon Linux 2? JFYI, a command to check: `awk -F '[="]*' '/^PRETTY_NAME/ { print $2 }' < /etc/os-release`

Comment: yes, please find this screenshot: https://github.com/uday-globuslive/duplicate1/raw/master/Untitled1.png

Comment: @encryptedname strange, I installed python this way two times on amazon linux 2. Next time I'll try to walk through it again and check what might be missing

Comment: @encryptedname possibly you have to run `sudo amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8` first

Answer (score 2):

Use :

1. `sudo yum -y groupinstall development sudo yum -y install zlib-devel`
2. `sudo yum -y install openssl-devel bzip2-devel sudo yum remove python`
3. `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/Python-3.10.4.tgz`
4. `tar xzvf Python-3.10.4.tgz`
5. `cd Python-3.10.4/`
6. `sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations`
7. `sudo make install`

https://en.linuxteaching.com/article/how_to_install_python_39_on_amazon_linux#how_do_i_install_python_36_on_amazon_linux_2

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) [aws](/questions/tagged/aws) [amazon-linux-2](/questions/tagged/amazon-linux-2) [ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial link you have posted makes you install python interpreter in a /opt folder not the /usr/bin or anywhere standard binaries are installed.So a workaround would this be :-

Just `add your python interpreter Path to your Environment PATH variable`, so that your shell knows where to find `python interpreter.`

But before that go to /opt folder nd determine your interpreter's full path using `pwd` command and then execute the following.

type `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/python3.8/python` and press enter ( for example)

or you can also do this `specify the python interpreter path on top of your script`

example

```
#!/opt/python3.8/bin/python
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```